# How to make my feed tidy

Tags: rss, feed

I looked up 'how to get the rss feed for your wordpress blog'

...and discovered I just need to add /feed to the url of my blog.

So that's this: http://richardclunan.com/blog/feed/

It looks really messy though.

What do I need to do to make it tidy?

Or is there another way to get a feed url for my blog that will already be tidy?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with _tidy_.

Comment: Feeds are not meant for people, not directly. Feed readers (sometimes built into the browser) parse them and display them. The way it looks depends on the reader.

Comment: thanks. i'll change my question to how do i check it in a feed reader...